# Enable scrolling of children when the body is set `overflow: hidden`?

Tags: html, css

I have a following html. How can I enable scrolling of the `innerDiv`?

```
<html>
<body style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="innerDiv">
        H <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        I<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        !<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p> Can you see me? </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried setting `#innerDiv { overflow: scroll }`, but what it does is no more than adding a empty scrollbar on the right.

//Edit: the height of innerDiv is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is expected because the height of your div is not fixed, so its height will be the height of its content. This lead to the fact that no content is overflown and no scrollbars are needed. The div height should be fixed or set to the parent height.

Answer (score 1):

you not fix the the height of #innerDiv so its height. change according to content try this

```
#innerDiv 

{ 

    overflow: auto;

    height:40px; //as your required

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide height to the div.

```html
<body style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div id="innerDiv" style="overflow: auto;height:100px;">
        H <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        I<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        !<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p> Can you see me? </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you set the overflow style to hidden in the body? I can't seem to get the idea of that. Just remove that property and leave it to it's deffault prop aka visible and it should work.